# Simplify multiple SQL involving "order by date desc limit 1"

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following SQL to extract the most recent `invoice` for a given `bill`

```
SELECT  "invoices".* FROM "invoices"  WHERE "invoices"."bill_id" = ?  ORDER BY issue_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

I run it for each `bill_id` in a set, say `[1, 5, 7, 9]`.  Is there a way to execute these 4 SQL commands with just one?

EDIT::  To clarify, I have 4 bills, and each bill has multiple invoices.  I want the most recent invoice for each bill.  So a total of 4 invoices.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "bills" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "title" varchar(255))
CREATE TABLE "invoices" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "issue_date" datetime, "amount_cents" integer, "bill_id" integer)
```

Comment: Could you show us the schema?

Comment: I think you need to use the in keyword. where "invoices"."bill_id" in (1, 5, 7, 9)

Comment: @Jonny . . . The OP is trying to get four rows back, not one row.

Comment: **Don't quote/backtick your column names.**  They are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea as well, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
SELECT *
FROM  invoices
WHERE bill_id IN (1,5,7,9)
GROUP BY bill_id HAVING MAX(issue_date);
```

test on the same data @Fabien posts: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f4f27/13)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query :

```
 SELECT  i.* 
 FROM invoices AS i
 WHERE i.bill_id in (1,5,7,9)
 AND i.issue_date = (SELECT li.issue_date 
                     FROM invoices AS li
                     WHERE i.bill_id = li.bill_id
                     ORDER BY li.issue_date DESC LIMIT 1)
```

See SQLFIDDLE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f4f27/3/0

or you can do it with the `MAX` function and a `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT  i.* 
FROM invoices AS i
WHERE i.bill_id in (1,5,7,9)
AND i.issue_date = (SELECT MAX(li.issue_date)
                    FROM invoices AS li
                    WHERE i.bill_id = li.bill_id
                    GROUP BY li.bill_id)
```

See SQLFIDDLE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f4f27/4/0